# What does mysql after find first result, if in where clause is unique indexed column

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE login = 'Jhon' AND password = '123'
```

column `login` has unique index, `password` not indexed.

After find first result, mysql will stop execution or not?

Comment: No, it will still search the whole table.  You will also need LIMIT 1

Comment: and when in  WHERE clause is just `WHERE login = 'Jhon'`, mysql will also search the whole table?

Comment: The `select` command is always for the whole table whether there is a filter condition (where clause) or not

Comment: advermark, Saju - Thanks very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE login = 'Jhon' AND password = '123'
```

Is fine, limit isn't necessary since you're filtering on a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT/INDEX.

As an aside, don't store plain text passwords in your database.

If login is a unique index the query will stop searching the index b-tree once it finds 'Jhon'. Because you have two conditions the Login and Password you may want to hint to MySQL to use the login index, to avoid (what should technically be impossible) a mis-optimization of the query plan.

```
SELECT id FROM mytable USE INDEX(login) WHERE login = 'Jhon' AND password = '123'
SELECT id FROM mytable FORCE INDEX(login) WHERE login = 'Jhon' AND password = '123'
```